# How to rid of Eslint errors that not allowing Vue app from running?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

My Vue cli was running fine until I stopped it for a moment to check something and when I tried to run it again, I got this error : Syntax Error: TypeError: eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor.
Note: I already removed the package-lock.json & node_modules and reinstalled them to fix some vulnerability issues but npm audit fix --froce does not work for me !

Here’s my code:

### Error

[image]

### package.json

```json
     {
      "name": "frontend",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "vue": "^3.0.0",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
        "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.44.0",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.0"
      }
    }
```

### main.js

````
```vue
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from './router'
    import store from './store/store'
        
    import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
    import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
        
    library.add(fas)
        
    // Vue.config.productionTip = false
        
     createApp(App)
         .use(store)
         .use(router)
         .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
         .mount('#app')
   ```
````

Comment: see this  https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6759#issuecomment-945887485

Comment: After trying too many ways to solve the problem, the only thing that is worked for me is actually to remove all eslint from package.json and run the app again. That is it !

Answer (score 1):

You should check update @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@next to support eslint v8.x

Comment: I had thought about that but I thought maybe it's better to update once i finish the development part in order to avoid other problems that might be related to version issues or compiling